# Python: Vectorize on a 4-d array

Tags: python, vectorization

I have 4-d arrays of wind speed (time, ht, x, y) which I'm attempting to calculate turbulent kinetic energy from. In order to do this, at each time step and at each height, I must calculate the average of the three wind components, subtract that average from the speed at each grid point, calculate the TKE at each grid point, and average it at that height. This results in a lot of loops as you can see in my code below. I ran this once and it took over a week to run, which is not conducive to quick analysis.

My question: Is there a way to vectorize the processes going on in these loops to help my code run faster? I've seen examples on 1- and 2-d arrays, but nothing on the scale of what I'm trying to do.

```
tkehgt = np.empty((289,39),np.float32)
for c in range(0,289,1):
    print count
    u_avg = np.empty((39),np.float32)
    v_avg = np.empty((39),np.float32)
    w_avg = np.empty((39),np.float32)
    for d in range(hgt_final.shape[1]):
        u_avg[d] = np.average(u[c,d,:,:])
        v_avg[d] = np.average(v[c,d,:,:])
        w_avg[d] = np.average(w[c,d,:,:])
    for e in range(hgt_final.shape[1]):
        tkegrid = np.empty((300,300),np.float32)
        for f in range(hgt_final.shape[2]):
            for g in range(hgt_final.shape[3]):
                uprime = u[c,e,f,g] - u_avg[e]
                vprime = v[c,e,f,g] - v_avg[e]
                wprime = w[c,e,f,g] - w_avg[e]
                tkegrid[f,g] = 0.5*(uprime**2+vprime**2+wprime**2)
        tkehgt[count,e] = np.average(tkegrid[:,:])
```

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your dataframe?

Comment: @rahlf23 All my data is in netCDF files on a remote server, so that's kinda tricky. If you want "real" data to work with, it might be easier to just do a np.random.rand(289,39,300,300)*10 -- or a smaller array if you like -- for u, v, and w.